# patch endpoint test using rest assured mock mvc

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, rest-assured, mockmvc, json-patch

I am trying to write a test for patch end point using rest assured mock mvc.
But i am not able to create an object of jsonmerge patch to place in the body of the mock.below is the end point for which i need to wrote the test

```
     @PatchMapping(path = "/{orderId}", consumes = "application/merge-patch+json")
     public OrderDTO updateOrder(@PathVariable Long orderId, @RequestBody 
                                                       JsonMergePatchImpl patchRequest){
    return facade.patchOrder(orderId,patchRequest);


}
```

and following is what i'm trying but not able to figure out

```
            Mockito.when(facade.patchOrder(any(),any())).thenReturn(orderDTO);
            OrderDTO actual=given()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .body()
            .accept("application/merge-patch+json")
            .when()
            .patch(BASE_URL+"/"+1l)
            .then()
            .assertThat()
            .statusCode(200).extract().as(OrderDTO.class);
```

My problem is i am not able to create an object for jsonmerge patch , and what to put in as content type

Answer (score 1):

You can specify contentType as String:

```
.contentType("application/merge-patch+json")
```